# embed causes discord error 400 despite being less than 2000 characters

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Exactly as it says in the title. I have a troublesome embed. It works most of the time, but occasionally despite feeding it exactly the same data every time it throws up a discord 400 and ruins everything.

I have tried to create a regressive loop to catch the exception and just motor thru until it works. this worked for a little while, but not all the time.

```py
async def ManageRollRoyalleRoll(thePlayer):
    output=None
    try:
        output = await MakeRollRoyalleRoll(thePlayer)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        output = await ManageRollRoyalleRoll(thePlayer)
    return output
```

Is there another discord exception i should be using? because after a week of trawling here and other sites this is all i can come up with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY found it.

```py
async def ManageRollRoyalleRoll(thePlayer):
    output=None
    try:
        output = await MakeRollRoyalleRoll(thePlayer)
    except discord.errors.HTTPException:
        output = await ManageRollRoyalleRoll(thePlayer)
    return output
```

this works like a dream.